# SQL Server CAST a CASE on

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying have a SELECT statement from a tinyint column and decode it.

Example:

1. SimpleText
2. MoreText
3. AnotherText

I've read in other posts that you use a CAST/CONVERT statement but I keep getting the same error that it cannot convert 'MoreText' to int.

My statement is the following

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[OneColumn]
      ,[UselessColumn]
        ,CAST (CASE 
            WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 1 THEN 'SimpleText'
            WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 2 THEN 'MoreText'
            WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 3 THEN 'AnotherText'
        ELSE 'NoText' END AS nvarchar(20)) AS [ProblemColumn]
      ,[ColumnNotImportant]
FROM [sof].[ExampleTable]
```

I've also tried

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[OneColumn]
      ,[UselessColumn]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 1 THEN CAST('SimpleText' AS nvarchar(20))
            WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 2 THEN CAST('MoreText' AS nvarchar(20))
            WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 3 THEN CAST('AnotherText' AS nvarchar(20))
        ELSE 'NoText' END  AS [ProblemColumn]
      ,[ColumnNotImportant]
FROM [sof].[ExampleTable]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the above queries generated the error

Comment: I'm thinking that whatever you're doing with the result of this query is the problem.  Is the error coming from SQL or from code?  It's likely that you generated a DTO object with the original type of ImportantColumn (int), and didn't change it when you changed what was coming back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need a cast at all?

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[OneColumn]
      ,[UselessColumn]
        ,CASE WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 1 THEN 'SimpleText'
              WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 2 THEN 'MoreText'
              WHEN [ImportantColumn] = 3 THEN 'AnotherText'
              ELSE 'NoText' 
         END AS [ProblemColumn]
      ,[ColumnNotImportant]
FROM [sof].[ExampleTable]
```

Comment: He said he is getting error,  *cannot convert 'MoreText' to int.*

Comment: @Prdp: Yep, but since there is no cast to `int` in this query i doubt that he has shown the relevant part or simplified it. That's why my suggestion was to remove the redundant `CAST`. That should either work or show a more meaningful error.

Comment: Hi @Tim, Without the cast I get the same error, actually at the begging I used nothing but the CASE, after the error I started searching for answers here and they come with the solution of the CAST/CONVERT and neither of those work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The error was coming from the query as was bring in the original column type, but you were right I fixed it and take out the CAST and still Work.

Answer (score 0):

Let SQL do the work for you. Create a table with the ImportantColumn values as one column and the text you want to display as the 2nd column. Then change your query to be a join against that table.

The key to the lookup table is the values of ImportantColumn.

Comment: Hey @n8wrl, well that is my last resource but that brings to my mind some more questions, one of them is Will it take longer to process the query?

Comment: @XavierLace: Doubtful but your best bet is to measure it. This solution has many advantages - you can use it other places w/o duplicating code and your logic is now more data-driven, which is a good thing